# We look forward to reviewing your resubmitted app without in-app purchases

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am facing a small issue in review process of IOS. I submitted an app where I have integrated in-app purchase. Now for some reasons we made it free of cost, so submitted latest version without in-app purchase. But IOS team always rejects the app with following reason:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for your reply. We appreciate your efforts to comply with
> the App Store Review Guidelines, and we look forward to reviewing your
> resubmitted app without in-app purchases.
>
> Best regards,
>
> App Store Review

Can someone help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: what exactly is made for free? the app or the items or service you provide within the app ?

Comment: The service provided in the app is for free, previously it used to be 8$

Comment: It seems like you uploaded the wrong version again. why dont you try to contact apple developers support

Comment: I already tried asking for a support call, they are going to call me tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: happy to help =)